# Parallax scroll of non-full width divs in Pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations, parallax

I have two divs side by side, which are not full width on a page. The left div contains a background image, while the right will contain pieces of text, etc. The left hand side's height is based upon the amount of content in the right, but both are equal width.

What I am aiming to do is to have them do a sort of parallax scroll, where the left div moves faster than the right. Furthermore, I'd like to have the background image on the left move slightly the opposite direction so that the image itself scrolls more into view, up to the point where it's centered.

I have already implemented a version of this using javascript and performing actions on scroll events. However, I feel that this is not an efficient method, as scroll is called so often, and this piece of html could be on the same page many times. A throttler/debouncer is not an option as it negatively affects the smoothness of the animation. Furthermore, I'm starting to see the issues creep up where differences between mobile and desktop view are breaking in places. Where this would be easy to override in CSS, it's more of a pain with JS/JQuery. **Therefore, I'd like to know if it is possible to do this effect with CSS only.**

I have seen a lot of tutorials on parallax purely with CSS, but almost all of the ones I've seen are for page width items, and I'm having trouble translating it to a smaller block. The best I can get is for the background image to be parallax, where you can see it scroll, but the container block itself doesn't actually move any different.

Any help in doing this purely with CSS and CSS animations would be much appreciated.

**Current code using JS:**
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GenericSnake/tdvaf7sp/3/)
OR

```js
    function parallaxScroll() {
            var parallaxElement = $(".imageside"),
                parallaxQuantity = parallaxElement.length;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < parallaxQuantity; i++) {
                    var currentElement = parallaxElement.eq(i),
                        windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
                        elementTop = currentElement.offset().top,
                        elementHeight = currentElement.height(),
                        viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.5 - elementHeight * 0.5,
                        scrolled = windowTop - elementTop + viewPortHeight,
                        wrapperScrolled = scrolled * -0.4,
                        backgroundScrolled = scrolled * 0.15;

                    if (backgroundScrolled <= 0) {
                        currentElement.css({
                            transform: "translateY(" + scrolled * -0.4 + "px)" //Make image div scroll up the way. 
                        });
                        currentElement.css('background-position-y', scrolled * 0.3); //Put background image the opposite way to create animation effect.
                    }

                    else {
                        currentElement.css({
                            transform: "translateY(" + scrolled * -0.4 + "px)" //Make image div scroll up the way.  
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
    }
    
  $(window).on("load scroll", function () {
                parallaxScroll();
            });
```

```css
.demo-wrapper {
  padding: 500px 20px;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}


.column {
   flex: 1;
   position: relative;
}

.right-side-wrapper {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}


.imageside {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.right-side {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    margin: 50px 50px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo-wrapper">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="column">
       <div class="imageside" style="background-image: url(https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg);"></div>
     </div>
   
   
     <div class="column right-side-wrapper">
       <div class="right-side">
         <h2 class="quote-title"></h2>


         <div class="right-side-item quote-wrapper">
           <blockquote class="quoted-text">
             Lorem ipsumdas d ds asd asd asd 
             asd asda dasdasd a
             as dasd asdsd a
           </blockquote>
         </div>

       </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that is impossible because we have no scroll position based unit.
you can change the direction of an element with some styles(transform for example) but cannot move it by scrolling

Comment: With "change direction" could you have a similar effect as to my example? I don't necessarily need to recreate the js exactly, more recreate the style of the animation.